# How do I make the Login page identify the type of users?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using html, PHP and MySQL(phpmyadmin). This might be a very simple question but I am a beginner so this is very new to me. My system has has 4 types of users.
Lets say user type 1 has a username Tom, user type 2 has a username Alice, user type 3 has a username Mike and user type 4 has a username Mary. 
I want the Login page to identify which type of user it is when the username is written. For instance, if it is Tom, I want the system to identify that he is user type 1 and redirect him to a specific page. Likewise if it is Alice, her user type should be identified and she should be redirected to another page. Not the same page as user type 1.
Please let me know of the simplest ways this could be achieved. Thank you so much in advance.

This is what I have done so far. But it is not working. Please let me know what I have to do.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
$usertype = $_POST ['user_type'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    if ($username ['user_type'] == admin) {
        header('location: localhost/adminhomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($username ['user_type'] == po) {
        header('location: localhost/pohomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($username ['user_type'] == pw) {
        header('location: localhost/pwhomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($username ['user_type'] == ps) {
        header('location: localhost/pshomepage.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "error determining user type!";
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid login information. Please try again.";
    exit();
}
```

}

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: See my edits based on your latest code update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, create a separate column like role in mysql.Based on the usertype put values in that column like if usertype 1=role is 1 ,usertype 2=role is two...

On particular login based on value in column name role,redirect user to the with respective page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is based on your last code addition edit**

```
// Needs to be at the top of every page
// This is used to recall your user status
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // You need to sanitize this or you have a potential security issue
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ['username']);

    // You should not be storing in plain text. You should have this encrypted
    // You should store it with PHP's latest encryption functions or at least do
    // a salt + hash.....but at least do a hash
    // hash("sha512", $_POST['password']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    // I am not sure of the relevance of this field
    $usertype = $_POST['user_type'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";

    // You should be using mysqli_ or PDO with prepared statements
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

// You need to fetch the results. All you have done is check if user exists
 if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
    // Fetch results
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // You should set results to a session for later checking
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user['user_type'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];

    // You have to quote the checks or they are invalid
    if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        header('location: localhost/adminhomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'po') {
        header('location: localhost/pohomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'pw') {
        header('location: localhost/pwhomepage.php');
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'ps') {
        header('location: localhost/pshomepage.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "error determining user type!";
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid login information. Please try again.";
    exit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column in your database for user type. It usually makes sense to create the column with a default value unless they will always be unique.

```
/*/your SQL query/*/

//if you need to validate type throughout the site, setup sessions as @Rasclatt suggested//

if ($user['type'] == 1) {
    header('location: http://domain.com/page1.html');
}else if ($user['type'] == 2) {
    header('location: http://domain.com/page2.html');
}else if ($user['type'] == 3) {
    header('location: http://domain.com/page3.html');
}else if ($user['type'] == 4) {
    header('location: http://domain.com/page4.html');
}else{
    echo "error determining user type!";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a column in your user table named user_type.
add user type while user registration.
after that while log in you can check by your query which user type is logging in.

and if you want to show your user type on next page, you can store user_type in session.

feel free to ask any further problems.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a MySQL skills to get what you want, because the user type/role depends on different MySQL table's. 
for example...
In almost every website you notice that there is a admin, user and also some has their one sub admin or many. All have their different rights and when they try to login then each one redirect to their specified page, like user will be redirected to home page, admin's will redirect to admin panel index etc..

Now you need to create different table for each user in MySQL and assign them different rights, or you can also create different column based on Boolean values like 0 for some action and 1 for some action...
 Hope it will help you...